# Flutter: Toggle PopupMenuButton based on the Signed in State

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: Expanded PopupMenuButton]

The Sign In button in the picture in on the Homescreen and it leads to a login screen. From the login screen if the user is authenticated,the screen `pop`s back to HomeScreen.

What I am looking for is a way to update that button to be swapped with a *Sign Out* button. My current code can only do that if the app is killed and restarted.

Here is my simplified code below:
The following is the build method of a Stateful Widget

```
bool loggedIn = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
        child: Image.asset(
          'image/address.png',
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        showLogin(loggedIn, context),
      ],
    ),
```

The current `showLogin` method which switches to *Sign Out* only after killing and restarting the app.

```
showLogin(bool loggedIn, BuildContext context) {
  if (!loggedIn) {
    return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: choiceAction,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ["Sign In"].map((String choice) {
          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: choice,
            child: Text(choice),
          );
        }).toList();
      },
    );
  } else {
    return PopupMenuButton<String>(
      onSelected: choiceAction,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ["Sign Out"].map((String choice) {
          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: choice,
            child: Text(choice),
          );
        }).toList();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
void choiceAction(String choice) {
  switch (choice) {
    case ("Sign In"):
    //Navigate to the nextScreen value
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen(0)));
      break;
    case ("Sign Out"):
      setSignedOutState(); //Sets state. So Sign Out to Sign in works just fine.
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a StreamBuilder? (I tried doing it, but still don't understand `streamBuilder`s all that well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside choiceAction() you need to perform switch operation inside setState method.

And toggle the value of loggedIn depending upon your case inside switch.

```
void choiceAction(String choice) {
  setState((){
  switch (choice) {
    case ("Sign In"):
    //Navigate to the nextScreen value
      loggedIn = true;
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen(0)));
      break;
    case ("Sign Out"):
      loggedIn = false;
      setSignedOutState(); //Sets state. So Sign Out to Sign in works just fine.
      break;
    default:
  }
  };
}
```